# Problem enabling curl in php.ini on Xampp for WinXP

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I'm trying to enable curl, for PHP, after I recently installed Xampp on WinXP. 
The versions of components are:
Apache 2.2.17
PHP 5.3.4
MySQL 5.5.8

It should just be a matter of removing the semicolon (as I've done before many times, on other Win WAMP installs) and making sure the .dll is in place.
( It is: in this case I have C:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll )

Of course I restart Apache to re-read the .ini config file and for the new changes to take effect.

After this, reviewing the output of  phpinfo(), I do not see curl. 
Help if you can, or know what the issue is.  Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Are you sure, that you are changing correct php.ini? Run `phpinfo.php` and check "Loaded Configuration File" path in first table.

Answer (score 0):

Being on Xampp 1.7.4 there is only one php.ini (thankful for that) 
I see in past versions there have been different configurations.

I'm happy to report this has been resolved, after I rebooted.
Not sure why that was required, but it worked.